# environment settings in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am wondering if I change the settings in spark-env.sh for the worker nodes, will that be changed for that executor? I know SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES is applied for each executor, I can see that in web UI, but what about the rest?
I have set this for one executor, i am not able to verify if this settings is indeed being applied for this worker node. I am using spark standalone in cluster mode.

```
SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=4
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=6G
```

Is there any way of verifying the settings for each executor node? If not, is there a way I can apply different settings for different executor?

Thanks and Regards,
Sudip